# Skip to the next iteration when download.file takes too long

Tags: r, loops, time

I have been trying to skip a iteration of `download.file` that takes too long and it is not working accordingly, though I've tried some similar [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346619/how-to-stop-a-function-in-r-that-is-taking-too-long-and-give-it-an-alternative) to my problem. I've set an example below with the code that I have been using. My main problem is that some of the IDs (from the `vec` object below) that I am using to extract the .csv files do not possess a related .csv file and the URL does not work adequately -- I believe it keeps trying the URL until it gets a response, which it does not, and the loop starts taking too long. How can I skip an ID if `download.file` starts taking too long?

```
library(stringr)
library(R.utils)    

vec=c("05231992000181","00628708000191","05816554000185", "01309949000130","07098414000144", "07299568000102", "12665438000178", "63599658000181", "12755123000111", "12376766000154",
      "11890564000163", "04401095000106", "11543768000128", "10695634000160", "34931022000197", "10422225000190",
      "09478854000152", "12682106000100", "11581441000140", "10545688000149", "10875891000183", "13095498000165",
      "10809607000170", "07976466000176", "11422211000139", "41205907000174", "08326720000153", "06910908000119",
      "04196935000227", "02323120000155", "96560701000154")


for (i in seq_along(vec)) {

  url = paste0("http://compras.dados.gov.br/licitacoes/v1/licitacoes.csv?cnpj_vencedor=", vec[i])

  tryCatch(expr = {evalWithTimeout(download.file(url, 
                                                 destfile = paste0("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/example_file/",vec[i],".csv"),  
                                                 mode="wb"), timeout=3)},
           error=function(ex) cat("Timeout. Skipping.\n"))

  print(i)
}
```

Comment: A better idea than timeouts is to use [httr](http://httr.r-lib.org/) so you can check [the HTTP status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), as you're almost certainly getting a failing status for the nonexistent files.

Comment: Which function? I've tried `http_error` and it does seem to be the adequate one...

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do. I'd probably use `GET` instead of `download.file`, then just extract the `status` part of the response, and if it's good, call `content` on it. `warn_for_status` would probably do the same thing, though I haven't used it before. I'm not really sure why you're trying to throw errors, though—they'll stop your code, which you don't really want to do.

Comment: I do not think it works -- from the looks of it, it still needs a lot of time to obtain the `status` with `GET`.

Comment: Hmm, apparently there's some issue with the server. You can set a timeout on the call and catch the error still, e.g. `lapply(paste0('http://compras.dados.gov.br/licitacoes/v1/licitacoes.csv?cnpj_vencedor=', c("01309949000130", "07098414000144")), function(x) tryCatch(httr::GET(x, httr::timeout(3)), error = function(e) NULL))`

Comment: Eesh, even some of the ones that return are just empty.

Comment: Yes, but anyhow that kind of solves it for now. I need to get what is attainable. If you want to post this as the answer, I will set it as the correct one -- since it clearly answers what I asked, i.e. something to jump to the next iteration if it takes too long to get a response from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When possible, HTTP status is an efficient way to deal with this situation, but if the server is not responding, you can set a timeout with `httr::timeout`, passed to `httr::GET`. Keeping everything in neat data frame list columns via the tidyverse,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

base_url <- "http://compras.dados.gov.br/licitacoes/v1/licitacoes.csv?cnpj_vencedor="
df <- data_frame(cnpj_vencedor = c("05231992000181", "00628708000191", "05816554000185", "01309949000130","07098414000144", "07299568000102", "12665438000178", "63599658000181", "12755123000111", "12376766000154", "11890564000163", "04401095000106", "11543768000128", "10695634000160", "34931022000197", "10422225000190", "09478854000152", "12682106000100", "11581441000140", "10545688000149", "10875891000183", "13095498000165","10809607000170", "07976466000176", "11422211000139", "41205907000174", "08326720000153", "06910908000119", "04196935000227", "02323120000155", "96560701000154")) 

df <- df %>% 
    # iterate GET over URLs, modified by `purrr::safely` to return a list of 
    # the result and the error (NULL where appropriate), with timeout set
    mutate(response = map(paste0(base_url, cnpj_vencedor), 
                          safely(httr::GET), httr::timeout(3)))

df <- df %>% 
           # extract response (drop errors)
    mutate(response = map(response, 'result'),
           # where there is a response, extract its data 
           data = map_if(response, negate(is.null), httr::content))

df
#> # A tibble: 31 x 3
#>    cnpj_vencedor  response       data              
#>    <chr>          <list>         <list>            
#>  1 05231992000181 <S3: response> <tibble [49 × 18]>
#>  2 00628708000191 <S3: response> <NULL>            
#>  3 05816554000185 <S3: response> <tibble [1 × 18]> 
#>  4 01309949000130 <S3: response> <NULL>            
#>  5 07098414000144 <NULL>         <NULL>            
#>  6 07299568000102 <NULL>         <NULL>            
#>  7 12665438000178 <NULL>         <NULL>            
#>  8 63599658000181 <NULL>         <NULL>            
#>  9 12755123000111 <NULL>         <NULL>            
#> 10 12376766000154 <NULL>         <NULL>            
#> # ... with 21 more rows
```