# Stop Keras when fails to converge after a specified time

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning

I am using a straightforward application of the Keras API in R. Depending on the `set.seed(value)` value, sometimes it will converge and sometimes it won't. I assume because the seed sets the initially randomized weights. If it doesn't converge at first, I can usually get it to converge on a different run by changing the seed value, but I have to monitor/stop it manually. How can I stop Keras if the model hasn't converged after a specified time (e.g., stop it after 600 seconds and restart it with a different seed value).

```
  set.seed(42)
  x <- as.matrix(train_data)
  y <- as.matrix(train_targets)
  
  model = keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_dense(units=64, kernel_regularizer=regularizer_l2(0.001), activation="relu", input_shape=dim(train_data)[[2]]) %>%
    layer_dense(units=32, kernel_regularizer=regularizer_l2(0.001), activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units=1, activation="linear")
  
  model %>% compile(
    loss = "mse", 
    optimizer = "rmsprop",
    metrics = list("mae")
  )
  
  model %>% fit(x, y, epochs = 50,verbose = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to define a function that calls itself, perhaps performing an action like setting seed before doing so.
Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346619/how-to-stop-a-function-in-r-that-is-taking-too-long-and-give-it-an-alternative) and borrowing an example from the [keras guides](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guide/keras/) that requires a few seconds to run.

```
library(keras)
d <- dataset_mnist()
x_train <- d$train$x
y_train <- d$train$y
x_test <- d$test$x
y_test <- d$test$y

x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, c(nrow(x_train), 784))
x_test <- array_reshape(x_test, c(nrow(x_test), 784))
x_train <- x_train / 255
x_test <- x_test / 255
y_train <- to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test <- to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(784)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax')

model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)
```

We can make a recursive function that calls itself after a time out.

```
timed_fit <- function(t = 5) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  set.seed(t)
  message("seed set to ", t)
  setTimeLimit(cpu = t, elapsed = t, transient = TRUE)
  on.exit({setTimeLimit(cpu = Inf, elapsed = Inf, transient = FALSE)})
  tryCatch({
    model %>% fit(
      x_train, y_train, 
      epochs = 4, batch_size = 128, 
      validation_split = 0.2
    )
  }, error = function(e) {
    if (grepl("reached elapsed time limit|reached CPU time limit", e$message)) {
      message("\n timed out!\n") # or set another seed, continue
      timed_fit(t + 10)
    } else {
      # error not related to timeout
      stop(e)
    }
  })
}

timed_fit()
```

The `Sys.sleep(1)` is inserted to avoid errors not interrupting the process properly, despite showing up.

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks! Is there any reason you set the seed to the same value as the time limit? In my implementation, I made the time limit the same each call to avoid excessively increasing runtimes, but changed only the seed value

Comment: @coolhand For your case a fixed value for time is indeed preferable. I added the increasing time to illustrate how it works when code is run in the console, and ability to pass on arguments when an error is caught. One might want to, for example, store some information or visualization of the failed fit, a timestamp of when it failed etc.